# Unable to edit recurring event

Tags: civievent

When I attempt to save changes to an event that is part of a series (repeating), I am unable to save those changes to a single event, event onward or the entire series. Looking at the logs - I get the following error:

```
[warning] Deprecated function, use CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're hitting CRM-21764.  A patch has been submitted upstream; you can [apply it now](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11837) or wait for the Wednesday release, which contains it.